# Filtering a view with 2 tables with same database tables

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have created a view which contains 2 tables.
What I want is to filter each table data according to their transaction type for example table1 should show only Payables List and table2 should show only Reciveable List.

here is the code
Note When I navigate to the view server shows me The resource cannot be found.other views are fine. here is my code.
My project has BOL(EF Model) BLL(Business object) DAL(Data Access layer) and my main Mvc project

### View

```
@model shinwari_traders.Areas.Shinwari.Models.ADetailsVm
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>AccountDetails</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table id="Payables" class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            Date
        </th>
        <th>
            Discription
        </th>
        <th>
            Amount
        </th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model.Payables)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @item.Date
            </td>
            <td>
                @item.Discription
            </td>
            <td>
                @item.Amount
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

</table>

<table id="Reciveables" class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            Date
        </th>
        <th>
            Discription
        </th>
        <th>
            Amount
        </th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model.Reciveables)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @item.Date
            </td>
            <td>
                @item.Discription
            </td>
            <td>
                @item.Amount
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

</table>
```

### Controller

```
    public class AccountDetailsController : Controller
{
    private TransictionBs objbs;
    public AccountDetailsController() 
    {
        objbs = new TransictionBs(int accountid);
    }
    // GET: Shinwari/AccountDetails
    public ActionResult Index(int accountid)
    {     var v= new ADetails();
          v.Payable = objbs.GetALL().Where(p => p.AId==accountid&& p.tbl_TransictionType.Type.Contains("Payable"));
          v.Reciveable = objbs.GetALL().Where(r => r.AId==accountid && r.tbl_TransictionType.Type.Contains("Reciveable"));


        return View(v);
    }
}
```

}

### Model Class

```
    public class ADetailsVm
{
    public List<BOL.tbl_Transiction> Payables { get; set; }
    public List<BOL.tbl_Transiction> Reciveables { get; set; }

}
```

### DatabaseTable

```
 public partial class tbl_Transiction
{
    public int TId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> Date { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> AId { get; set; }
    public string Discription { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> PKR { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> Rate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> Amount { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> TTId { get; set; }

    public virtual tbl_Accounts tbl_Accounts { get; set; }
    public virtual tbl_TransictionType tbl_TransictionType { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a new view model with 2 collection properties one for each collection.

```
public class AccountDetailsVm
{
   public List<BOL.tbl_Transiction> Reciveable {set;get;}
   public List<BOL.tbl_Transiction> Payable {set;get;}
}
```

And in your GET action, create an object of this view model, fill these 2 properties.

```
public ActionResult Index(int accountid)
{
   var v=new AccountDetailsVm();
   //Load both the collection properties
   v.Payables = objbs.GetALL()
           .Where(p => p.AId==accountid && p.tbl_TransictionType.Type.Contains("Payable"));
   v.Reciveable = objbs.GetByID(accountid).tbl_TransictionType.Type.Contains("Reciveable");

   return View(v);
}
```

And your view is bound to the new view model. I just added the minimal code here. You can convert the rendering to a table.

```
@model AccountDetailsVm

<h1>Reciveable</h1>
@foreach(var item in Model.Reciveable)
{
  <p>@item.Amount</p> 
}

<h1>Payable</h1>
@foreach(var item in Model.Payable)
{
  <p>@item.Amount</p>
}
```

Comment: should i create 2 different views for each 1st then call them in one controller ? or just create partial view like u suggested

Comment: My answer is not suggesting to create partial view. But if you think this tabular data can be reused somewhere else, you can create a partial view and pass the 2 different collection to that.

Comment: Can u please tell me what should i do with the ur code.. i mean the AccountDetailsVm is a class model ? and and Should i change my Viewcode or create new view for AccountDetailsVm ?

Comment: Yes. Your view need to display 2 different lists. So we created a new view model class specific for that view. You need to change your existing view code to bind to the new view model as i mentioned in my answer.

Comment: Please have a look at the code i edited when i run my app it shows 404 error on this view

Comment: what url are you trying to access ?

Comment: http://localhost:53636/Shinwari/AccountDetails?accountid=2 this s the genrated url toughits getting the right id but still shows error

Comment: But your code is inside `AccountDetails` controller. so you should be accessing it like `localhost:53636/AccountDetails/Index?accountid=2` . Take a look at [this](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/asp-net-mvc-routing-overview-cs) to understand how routing works.

Comment: I have checked my code almost 88 times I am still not sure what am i missing.I am using Model 1st approach,I have created 3 projects in my mvc project 1st BOL(object layer for EFModel) 2nd BLL(Business logic that passes my Repositry system) 3rd DAL(Data Access Passes functions to BLL) and main project has the referance of BLL and BOL